# Attachments plugin cannot click media library button

Tags: plugins, attachments, media-library

I have installed the [Attachments plugin](https://github.com/jchristopher/attachments) (version 3.5.7) to upload multiple images to a post in my post type 'shop'.

**The problem:**

For some reason I cannot click the insert button of the media library opened by the Attachments plugin.

[image]

**What I have tried to do to find/solve the problem:**

1. Deactivated all plugins (except the Attachments plugin).
2. Changed my theme to another theme.
3. Tried on a local environment (XAMPP) and webserver as well.

**Things to notice:**

1. After activating the Attachments plugin Wordpress gives the following message:

> The plugin generated 181 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you find that there is "headers already sent" messages,
>   or problems arise with the RSS feeds or other problems, try this
>   plugin then disable or remove.

2. On my local environment as well as my webserver a have a lot of "Failed to load resource (404)" messages, because of images that does not load, because they don't exist, but this is not a problem in my opinion.

**Code in functions.php to create an instance for my "shop" post type**

```
/** 
 * Registers attachments to shop
 * post type with the attachments plugin
 */
function gtp_shop_attachments_register( $attachments ) {

    $fields = array(
        array(
            'name'      => 'title',                         // unique field name
            'type'      => 'text',                          // registered field type
            'label'     => __( 'Title', 'attachments' ),    // label to display
            'default'   => 'title',                         // default value upon selection
        ),
        array(
            'name'      => 'caption',                       // unique field name
            'type'      => 'textarea',                      // registered field type
            'label'     => __( 'Caption', 'attachments' ),  // label to display
            'default'   => 'caption',                       // default value upon selection
        ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'         => __( 'Attachments', 'gtp_translate' ),
        'post_type'     => array( 'shop' ),
        'position'      => 'normal',
        'priority'      => 'high',
        'filetype'      => null,
        'button_text'   => __( 'Attach images', 'gtp_translate' ),
        'modal_text'    => __( 'Attach', 'gtp_translate' ),
        'router'        => 'browse',
        'post_parent'   => false,
        'fields'        => $fields,
    );

    $attachments->register( 'shop_attachments', $args ); // unique instance name
}

add_action( 'attachments_register', 'gtp_shop_attachments_register' );
```

Comment: So you've narrowed down that the Attachments Plugin is the issue? Sounds like you need to bring this issue to the Author's attention so *they* can fix it.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Done that https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-click-media-library-button?replies=1#post-8354412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking other browsers, I found out that it was a Chrome problem. It looks like it has something to do with Google Chrome notifications. I fixed the problem with adding this CSS to my WordPress admin css file:

```
/* Chrome media library upload button fix */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .modal-open .rdr-notifier {
        display: none !important;   
    }
}
```

If someone has a better solution, let me know!